# Using Group by to sum the int value and string

Tags: sql

I want to select the Column of Uptime for 8 hour shift and when there is no production I wanted to show "NoProduction" on that select column.

For Example Raw Table look like this

| Uptime(hr) | Production_Day(0 or 1) | t_stamp(date and time) | Shift |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Feb 15 05:00:00 EST 2021 | Mor |
| 1 | 1 | Feb 15 06:00:00 EST 2021 | Mor |
| ---(so on up 13:00 and value of uptime for each hour is 1 and Production_day is 1) |  |  |  |
| 1 | 1 | Feb 15 13:00:00 EST 2021 | Mor |
| 0 | 0 | Feb 15 14:00:00 EST 2021 | Aft |
| ---(so on up to 21:00 and value of uptime for each hour is 0 and Production_day is 0) |  |  |  |
| 0 | 0 | Feb 15 21:00:00 EST 2021 | Aft |

And I want to have result like this

| Uptime | Shift |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | Mor |
| "NoProduction" | Aft |

Here is my sql query which I tried,

```
select SUM(case when Production_Day = 1 then Pastry1_1hrUpTime_Minutes else "NoProduction" end) as Uptime,  Max(Shift) as Shift
FROM Table
WHERE t_stamp >= FORMAT(getDate()-0,'yyyy-MM-dd 05:00:00') and t_stamp <= FORMAT(getDate()-0,'yyyy-MM-dd 21:00:00')
GROUP BY DATEADD(hh, ((DATEDIFF(hh, 0, t_stamp)+3)/8*8)-4, 0)
```

So anybody can help me, how to use sum int and string in same select statement.

Thanks

Comment: tag only dbms that you are using

Comment: Sum int values ,  cast the sum to string, replace the string "0" to "NoProduction" using `case`

Comment: @nishant please share values of column Pastry1_1hrUpTime_Minutes.

Comment: @Serg, I used cast and changed the format to String but I could not replace the 0 with "NoProduction". Can you please tell me where should I place the case statement?  Here is the SQL query after your suggestion.                                      Select cast(((SUM(case when Production_Day = 1 then Pastry1_1hrUpTime_Minutes else 0 end))) as varchar(254)) as Uptime ,Min(format(t_stamp,'dd/MM/yyyy')) as date, Max(Shift) as Shift                                                                                                                          Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: See the answer. BTW, `Min(format(t_stamp,'dd/MM/yyyy'))` ..  do you mean   `format(Min(t_stamp),'dd/MM/yyyy')` ?

Comment: @Serg sorry for confusion, Because word limit I could not post the whole query.                   
Select cast(((SUM(case when Production_Day = 1 then Pastry1_1hrUpTime_Minutes else 0 end))) as varchar(254)) as Uptime ,Min(format(t_stamp,'dd/MM/yyyy')) as date, Max(Shift) as Shift
FROM Fiscal_Data_P1
WHERE t_stamp >= FORMAT(getDate()-7,'yyyy-MM-dd 05:00:00') and t_stamp <= FORMAT(getDate()-0,'yyyy-MM-dd 05:00:00')
GROUP BY DATEADD(hh, ((DATEDIFF(hh, 0, t_stamp)+3)/8*8)-4, 0)

Comment: I used group by that's why I had to use SUM and MIN function.

Comment: My point is `Min(format(t_stamp,'dd/MM/yyyy'))` for` { 2021-07-29 , 2021-08-02}` will return '02/08/2021' Is it what you want?

Comment: Yes because, I have one hour data and I wanted to group them in one shift, that's why I used the Min (t_stamp) and show that day in query. (because T-stamp was group by the 8hrs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided `Pastry1_1hrUpTime_Minutes` is `int`, zero sum value will be casted to '0'.  Try

```
select case when Uptime ='0' then 'NoProduction' else Uptime end Uptime
    , -- more columns
from (
      select cast(SUM(case when Production_Day = 1 then Pastry1_1hrUpTime_Minutes else 0 end) as varchar(254)) as Uptime
      , -- more columns
      from ..
) t;
```